# PHP mail() works from command line but not apache

Tags: php, apache, email, command-line, sendmail

I'm trying to figure out why the mail function in PHP fails when called via web browser (i.e. apache), but I can run the same script from the command line using

> php -f mailtest.php

This is one of my client's Fedora servers, so I don't grok it completely, but I do have root access should I need to change anything.

from php.ini:

> sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i

Not sure if this could matter, but /usr/sbin/sendmail is a symlink to /etc/alternatives/mta, which is a symlink back to /usr/sbin/sendmail.sendmail. FWIW the apache user does have permission to run sendmail (tested sendmail directly from the command line).

```
OS: Fedora Core 7 Linux (kernel 2.6.23.17)  
Apache: 2.2.8  
PHP: 5.2.6
```

Any help here will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You may want to post this on serverfault.com

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I found the problem. SELinux was preventing apache from being able to use sendmail. To diagnose, I used

```
$ sestatus -b | grep sendmail  
httpd_can_sendmail                   off
```

Then to actually fix the problem:

```
$ restorecon /usr/sbin/sendmail
$ setsebool -P httpd_can_sendmail 1
```

Read more about it [here](http://www.linux-archive.org/fedora-selinux-support/38002-selinux-newbie.html).

Comment: Glad you figured it out. You should accept your own answer -- grants you rep, a badge, and lets others know the question is answered.

Comment: thanks, you led me in the right direction: i had a similar issue and after reading your post i got the idea that it might have something todo with my apparmor installation ... indeed, it was the problem.

Comment: tell me why this is set to off by default??

Comment: `setsebool -P httpd_can_sendmail 1` didn't work for me. I tried with `-V` option and it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

Is it a user permissions error? Your account and the one used to execute PHP scripts may have different privileges.

Comment: All users have permission to execute sendmail. I confirmed by running sendmail as the apache user.

Answer (score 0):

Anything in apache's error_log? Is PHP being run as an apache module or a CGI binary?

EDIT: Hmmm... nothing in the error log. What does the call to `mail(...)` return? Anything interesting in the mail log? This will vary depending on the MTA, often /var/log/maillog

EDIT 2: Is `safe_mode` turned on and are you using the `mail()` function's *additional_parameters* ?

Comment: nothing in the error log.

PHP is being run as an apache module.

Comment: also I've turned on all errors (i.e. error_reporting(E_ALL); ) and don't see any errors or warnings there either.

Answer (score 0):

This is my first answer here on StackOverflow! :o

So I had the same issue than you, matt! I use OpenSuse. I figured out that `postfix check` resulted with

```
postfix/postfix-script: warning: not owned by group maildrop: /usr/sbin/postqueue
postfix/postfix-script: warning: not owned by group maildrop: /usr/sbin/postdrop
postfix/postfix-script: warning: not set-gid or not owner+group+world executable: /usr/sbin/postqueue
postfix/postfix-script: warning: not set-gid or not owner+group+world executable: /usr/sbin/postdrop
```

so I ran the next commands:

```
# my postfix user is postfix and postfix group is maildrop
sudo chown 'postfix:maildrop' /usr/sbin/post{drop,queue}
sudo chmod g+s /usr/sbin/post{queue,drop}
```

and then, I tried to simple PHP script from my browser to test if everything works fine: (assuming you want to mail abc@gmail.com)

```
<?php
$ret = mail('abc@gmail.com', 'subject', 'message');
if ($ret === true)
  echo 'Success'.PHP_EOL;
else
  echo 'Error'.PHP_EOL;
```

and that's fine! I hope you will fix the issue with this method