# Not able to send mail when running through webserver but able to send from command line with same php script

Tags: php, apache, email, https, command

I'm facing a weird problem: I have a file called mail.php in the project. When I run the command from shell:

```
php mail.php
```

it sends mail in seconds, but when running the same file as:

```
https://www.domain.com/mail.php
```

No mail is going out, using this code:

```
<?php
      echo "Sending mail now....";
      mail("mr.atanu.dey.83@gmail.com", "PHP Test mail", "Hope this works! ");
?>
```

Can somebody help me?

Comment: It may be related to many things, did you checked the logs? php.ini files may be different for cli, cgi, apache, fpm, so it may be configs or user permissions

Comment: I checked logs, when running through web server, the error log report is: Program mode requires special privileges, e.g., root or TrustedUser. Any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP mail() works from command line but not apache](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1462941/php-mail-works-from-command-line-but-not-apache)

Comment: have you resolved this issue? I have the same error in my error logs "Program mode requires special privileges, e.g., root or TrustedUser." on CentOS

Answer (score 1):

It may be the case that SELinux is enabled and according to SELinux default configuration the mail sending by apache/web server is not allowed.

To check whether SELinux is enabled and its configured to stop sending email run the below command:

```
getsebool -a | grep mail
```

## sample output

```
allow_postfix_local_write_mail_spool --> on
httpd_can_sendmail --> off
logging_syslogd_can_sendmail --> off
```

Now, in order to configured SELinux to allow apache to send email run the below command:

```
setsebool -P httpd_can_sendmail on
```

Check this answer, it resolve my issue:
[Not able to send mail when running through webserver but able to send from command line with same php script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8141514/not-able-to-send-mail-when-running-through-webserver-but-able-to-send-from-comma)

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution:

In php.ini replace

`sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i`

with

`sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail.postfix -t -i`

Then restart Apache.

Comment: no luck with the change .. its saying:

sh: /usr/sbin/sendmail.postfix: No such file or directory

in apache error log

Comment: what's in the maillog? do you have postfix installed? or what are you using?

Comment: Also: su /usr/sbin/setsebool -P httpd_can_sendmail on

Comment: I don't have SELinux Enabled so its saying:

"setsebool:  SELinux is disabled."

can't run the command. is there any alternative?

Comment: I had the same problem, and djdj's solution worked for me -- all I had to do was run the SELinux command and it started working.