# php mail() not working if called from terminal

Tags: sendmail, php

I'm trying to make a little newsletter. To send the E-Mails I would like to call the sender script with shell_exec().

```
<?php
$mail = new mail();
$mail->set('to', $to);
$mail->set('message', $content);
$mail->set('subject', 'Newsletter');
$mail->send();
?>
```

The mail() object is a simple class to send E-Mails and calls the php mail() function in the ->send() method. The header gets added before sending.

If i call this script in my browser on pageload, it works as it should. But on:

```
php send_mail.php
```

Nothing happens. The mail() function returns true and all parameters are correctly set if I'm outputting these before sending.

Also I checked /var/log/mail* but there is no error produced.

I tried calling the script by relativ and absolute path. Both don't work.

I'm stuck now because the mail() function only doesn't work if called from terminal, otherwise erverything seems fine.

I am using sendmail to send E-Mails.

How can I fix this?

Thank you :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1462941/php-mail-works-from-command-line-but-not-apache

Answer (score 1):

When using PHP from the command line it can often use a different php.ini file. It's likely that this CLI php.ini file doesn't have your mail settings configured.

Use `php -i` from the command line to find out which ini file PHP is using, then go check your mail settings in that file, particularly comparing with your normal apache php.ini file (which you can find by sticking `<?php phpinfo() ?>` in a script and loading it in a browser).

Answer (score 1):

i think, some configuration is missing for the cli mode.
compare php.ini, loaded from cli and from the webserver

```
ini_set ( "SMTP", "smtp-server.example.com" );
date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
```

could also help

Answer (score 0):

Check PHP mail configuration:

1. Open your php.ini file (if you don't know where this is, see below)
2. Search for the line that reads [mail function]
3. Add/change the details of your mail server. This could be a local mail server or the mail server of your ISP.
4. Save/close the php.ini file
5. Restart your web server

`[mail function];`

`For Win32 only.`

`SMTP = localhost`

`smtp_port = 25`

`For Win32 only.`

`sendmail_from = me@example.com`

`For Unix only.  You may supply arguments as well (default: "sendmail -t -i").`

`sendmail_path =`