# PHP can send email from command line but not browser

Tags: php

I have a form set up at my [homepage](http://prototypexenon.tech). When someone submits the form, it redirects them to a php script that sends me the form. The only issue is, the form won't send me anything when I use the browser. I have a script running on the same server that when I execute from the command line, sends an email immediately. When I go to the [page in a browser](http://prototypexenon.tech/emailtest.php), it gives a confirmation message, but won't send anything. What's happening? PHP is using MSMTP to send email if that helps. I *believe* apache is running as root (I know that's bad). How do I check?

Here's the code if anyone wants it:

```
<?php 
    ini_set( 'display_errors', 1 );
    error_reporting( E_ALL );
    $from = "mailbot@prototypexenon.tech";
    $to = "<MYEMAIL>";
    $subject = "PHP Mail Test script";
    $message = "This is a test to check the PHP Mail functionality";
    $headers = "From:" . $from;
    mail($to,$subject,$message, $headers);
    echo "Test email sent";
?>
```

EDIT: Apparently new-server-owner was smart enough to not let apache run as root. All fixed now. Thanks @EdHeal

Comment: Check your PHP error logs, and I think you'll see the reason.

Comment: could you please provide with the code snippet?

Comment: @PrototypeXenon - That would be better as an edit to the question. Also would the user that the script is running under have an influence to the permissions

Comment: @EdHeal got it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently new-server-owner was smart enough to not let apache run as root. All fixed now. Thanks @EdHeal

Answer (score 1):

PHP running via the command line and PHP running via a web server can use totally different php.ini files.  Run phpinfo() and see which php.ini file is being used in each case.  Probably one of them doesn't have SMTP properly configured.

Comment: locate php.ini or search for php.ini if your are on windows I get this /etc/php/7.0/cli/php.ini
/etc/php/7.0/fpm/php.ini
because I am using php-fpm but command line and browser ini's are usually different

Comment: @smugford It's running on Ubuntu. I am 100% I'm editing the right file.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1462941/php-mail-works-from-command-line-but-not-apache .... might be SeLinux