# Use PEAR on Fedora

Tags: fedora, pear

I am attempting to use PEAR to send email on a Fedora server machine and am getting nowhere.

Below is the code I am trying to use. The email authentication settings in the code are not the actual but the info I am using is pulled from my email client config so should work.

I am also trying to get debug info to find out what is happening. Is setting 'debug' to 'true' enough or is something else required? And where can I find the debug log information?

A lot of asks but I hope someone can direct me in the right direction.

I tried PHPMailer as well but no go. I have this sense that some configuration on the machine is blocking...

One more thing, this exact code works on a Ubuntu machine so I know it works. I am trying to move all services from the Ubuntu machine to a Fedora machine.

```
<?php

require_once "Mail.php";

$from = "demo@demo.com";
$recipients = 'demo@demo.com';
$headers["From"] = $from;
$headers["To"] = 'demo@demo.com';
$headers["Reply-To"] = $from;
$headers["Subject"] = 'Testing';
$headers["MIME-Version"] = "1.0";
$headers["Content-Type"] = "text/html; charset=UTF-8";

$body = 'Testing';

$smtpinfo["host"] = "mail.demo.com";
$smtpinfo["port"] = "587";
$smtpinfo["auth"] = true;
$smtpinfo["username"] = "demo@demo.com";
$smtpinfo["password"] = "password";
$smtpinfo["debug"] = true;

$mail_object = Mail::factory("smtp", $smtpinfo);
$mail_object->send($recipients, $headers, $body);

if (PEAR::isError($mail_object)) {
    $ret['success'] = false;
    $ret['msg'] = 'Message delivery failed...';
} else {
    $ret['success'] = true;
    $ret['msg'] = 'data is valid';
}

return $ret;

?>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, after a few more hours of testing I have resolved the issue. This [website](https://gist.github.com/tamouse/4085385)  provided direction on how to get debug information in the command line.

After testing the PHP code from the command line and confirming that messages can be sent, I attempted to send an email from a web page; which failed to work.

So, now thinking that the issue is likely related to the web server, led me to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1462941/php-mail-works-from-command-line-but-not-apache) on Stack Overflow . The solution of which resolved the issue immediately. Specifically, doing the following as described in the accepted solution:

```
$ sestatus -b | grep sendmail
httpd_can_sendmail    off

$ restorecon /usr/bin/sendmail
$ setsebool -P httpd_can_sendmail 1
```

Hope this helps someone else facing the some problem.

Comment: Thousands of points for setting the boolean correctly rather than just disabling selinux!